# Добавилось много иконок (font awesome) псевдоклассом

Tags: html, css3, bootstrap, иконки, fontawesome

Откуда взяли эти иконки??? У меня bootstrap отказывается корректно работать из за них... Распространились как блохи по странице.. Никогда такого не было.. Причем они распространены псевдоклассом ::before.. Инспектор говорит, что это подключенные через CDN иконки чудят.. Как их убрать? bootstrap отказывается работать.. Я добавил только одну... А добавилось куча...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
$('.modal1').click(function() {
     $('#modalwindow').arcticmodal()
    });
```

```css
body {
 font-family: Lato, sans-serif !important;
 color: #000;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
a {
 color: #000;
 text-decoration: none;
}
ul, li {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
.header_icon_1 {
 color: #000;
 padding-left: 18px;
 color: #fff;
}
header {
 background: #f4f4f5;
}
nav {
 font-size: 16px;
}
.header_item_color{
 color: #9f9fa1;
} 
.header_icon {
 margin-left: 13px;
 padding-right: 18px;
 color: #fff;
}
.header_item_back {
 background: #267df4;
 border-radius: 20px;
}
.nav-item {
 margin-right: 30px;
}
.nav-item:last-child {
 margin-right: 0;
}
.navbar-brand {
 margin-left: 70px;
}
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
 color: #9f9fa1;
}
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
 color: #000;
}
#header {
 padding-top: 30px;
}
#first {
 background: url(../img/first.png) no-repeat center top -100px /cover;
 min-height: 1200px;
}
.first_title {
 font-family: "Varela Round", sans-serif;
 font-size: 62px;
 margin-top: 100px;
}
.first_text {
 font-size: 20px;
 color: #8c8f94;
 margin-top: 60px;
}
.first_btn_video {
 margin-left: 12px;
}
.box-modal {
 width: 100%;
 padding: 20px;
}
.modal1 {
 padding: 5px 20px;
 border-radius: 20px;
 border: 1px solid #dbdce0;
 background: #eef0f3;
 margin-top: 60px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.modal1:hover {
 box-shadow:1px 1px 8px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1)inset;
 -webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 8px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1)inset;
 -moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 8px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1)inset;
}
.second_up_right_title,
.second_up_left_title {
 font-size: 26px;
 margin: 40px 0;
}
.second_up_left_text1,
.second_down_left_text1,
.second_up_right_text1,
.second_down_right_text1 {
 font-size: 18px;
 color: #8c8f94;
}
.second_down_left_back {
 background: url(../img/second_down_left.png) no-repeat center top /cover;
 min-height: 950px;
 margin-left: -398px;
 margin-top: 240px;
}
.second_down_title {
 font-family: "Varela Round", sans-serif;
 font-size: 42px;
 margin-top: 415px;
 margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.second_btn_icon {
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #fff;
 margin-left: 22px;
}
.second_down_right_text1 {
 margin-top: 35px;
}
.second_btn {
 background: #267df4;
 border-radius: 20px;
 padding: 7px;
 border: none;
 margin-top: 65px;
}
.fa-arrow-right {
 color: #fff;
 margin-left: 20px;
 margin-right: 22px;
}
button:active, button:focus, input:focus, input:active{
 outline: none;
}
.second_btn2 {
 background: #fff;
 border-radius: 20px;
 border: 1px solid #e9e9ea;
 padding: 7px;
 margin-left: 30px;
 margin-top: 65px;
}
.second_btn_icon2 {
 margin: 0 20px;
}
.third_left_title {
 font-family: "Varela Round", sans-serif;
 font-size: 42px;
 margin: 170px 0 55px 0;
}
.third_left_text {
 font-size: 20px;
 color: #8c8f94;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.third_left_title_h4 {
 font-size: 12px;
 font-weight: 900;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 3px;
 margin-bottom: 25px;
 margin-top: 60px;
}
.dropbox {
 margin-right: 25px;
}
.third_right_back {
 background: url(../img/map.png) no-repeat center top 160px;
 min-height: 660px;
 margin-right: -582px;
}
#third {
 padding-bottom: 200px;
}
.fourth_title {
 font-family: "Varela Round", sans-serif;
 font-size: 42px;
 margin-top: 140px;
}
#fourth {
 background: #f5f5f8;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
}
.fourth_title:before {
 content: '';
 display: block;
 width: 50px;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #267df4;
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -25px;
 margin-top: 80px;
}
.fourth_title_down {
 font-size: 12px;
 font-weight: 900;
 color: #8c8f94;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 margin-top: 65px;
}
.img1, .img2, .img3, .img5 {
 width: 320px;
}
.img4 {
 width: 369px;
}
.imgs_phone {
 margin-left: 27px;
}
.fourth_title_span_left {
 font-size: 12px;
 font-weight: 400;
 color: #a8a9af;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
.fourth_title_span_right {
 font-size: 12px;
 font-weight: 900;
 color: #a8a9af;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
.fourth_span_title {
 margin-top: 100px;
}
.fourth_title_down_h2 {
 font-family: "Varela Round", sans-serif;
 font-size: 42px;
 margin-top: 30px;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.fourth_form_input {
 width: 500px;
 border-radius: 25px;
 border: 1px solid #cbcbce;
 background: #f5f5f8;
 padding: 10px 0 10px 20px;
}
.fourth_form_input:placeholder {
 margin-left: 200px;
}
.fourth_form_button {
 width: 164px;
 border-radius: 20px;
 border: none;
 background: #6fc754;
 padding: 7px 0 7px 0;
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #fff;
 position: absolute;
 right: 26px;
 top: 4px;
}
.fourth_form_button i {
 margin-left: 20px;
}
.form_btn {
 margin-left: 20px;
}
.form_fourth {
 position: relative;
}
.fourth_form_down_text {
 font-size: 12px;
 color: #d4d5d9;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 65px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#fifth {
 margin: 0 auto !important;
}
.fifth_slider_item_title {
 font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
 font-size: 32px;
 font-weight: 400;
 color: #000;
}
.fifth_slider_item_text {
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: 400;
 color: #8c8f94;
}
.fifth_slider_name {
 font-size: 12px;
 font-weight: 900;
 color: #000;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,400,900" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/simple.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.arcticmodal-0.3.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slick-theme.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slick.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <header id="header">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-12">
     <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
             <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Tour</a>
             </li>
             <li class="nav-item">
                 <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
             </li>
             <li class="nav-item">
                 <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
             </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
         <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" alt=""></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"  data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded=" false " aria-label="Toggle navigation">
         <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
             <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Help</a>
             </li>
             <li class="nav-item">
                 <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contacts</a>
             </li>
             <li class="nav-item">
                 <a class="nav-link header_item_back" href="#"><i class="fa fa-apple header_icon_1"></i><span class="header_icon">Get  App</span></a>
             </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
     </nav>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </header>
 <section id="first">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-12 m-auto text-center">
     <h1 class="first_title">What happens tomorrow?</h1>
     <p class="first_text">
      The sight of the tumblers restored Bob Sawyer to a degree of equanimity which he had not possessed since his interview with his landlady. His face brightened up, and he began to feel quite convivial.
     </p>
     <button class="modal1"><i class="fa fa-play"><span class="first_btn_video">Watch Video</span></i></button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div style="display: none;">
      <div class="box-modal" id="modalwindow">
          <div class="box-modal_close arcticmodal-close">закрыть</div>
          <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/nNvAiwkTJyQ" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
  </div>
 </section>
 <section id="second">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
     <div class="second_up_left">
      <img src="img/second_lock.png" alt="Замок">
      <h3 class="second_up_left_title">Real-time all the time</h3>
      <p class="second_up_left_text1">Thus much I thought proper to tell you in relation to yourself, and to the trust I reposed in you.</p>
      <p class="second_down_left_text1">Just then her head struck against the roof of the hall: in fact she was now more than nine feet high, and she at once took up the little golden key and hurried off to the garden door.</p>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
     <div class="second_up_right">
      <img src="img/second_clock.png" alt="Будильник">
      <h3 class="second_up_right_title">Adopt without any obstacles</h3>
      <p class="second_up_right_text1">This sounded a very good reason, and Alice was quite pleased to know it. 'I never thought of that before!' she said.</p>
      <p class="second_down_right_text1">This I have produced as a scantling of Jack’s great eloquence and the force of his reasoning upon such abstruse matters.</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
     <div class="second_down_left_back">
      
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
     <h2 class="second_down_title">Your day<br>
     is protected</h2>
     <p class="second_down_right_text1">There have not been any since we have lived here,<br> said my mother.</p>
     <p class="second_down_right_text1">We thought - Mr. Copperfield thought - it was quite a<br> large rookery; but the nests were very old ones, and<br> the birds have deserted them a long while.</p>
     <button class="second_btn"><span class="second_btn_icon">Try to hack us</span><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
     <button class="second_btn2"><span class="second_btn_icon2">Learn more</span></button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
 <section id="third">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-5">
     <h3 class="third_left_title">We are almost
     everywhere</h3>
     <p class="third_left_text">Now the races of these two have been for some ages utterly extinct, and besides to discourse any further of them would not be at all to my purpose.</p>
     <p class="third_left_text">Thus much I thought proper to tell you in relation to yourself, and to the trust I reposed in you.</p>
     <h4 class="third_left_title_h4">Partners</h4>
     <img class="dropbox" src="img/dropbox.png" alt="fd">
     <img class="evernote" src="img/evernote.png" alt="fd">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-7">
     <div class="third_right_back">
      
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
 <section id="fourth">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
     <h2 class="fourth_title">Beautiful Interface</h2>
     <p class="fourth_title_down">Landing Screen</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="imgs_phone text-center">
   <img class="img1" src="img/1.png" alt="">
   <img class="img2" src="img/2.png" alt="">
   <img class="img4" src="img/4.png" alt="">
   <img class="img3" src="img/3.png" alt="">
   <img class="img5" src="img/5.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 m-auto text-center">
     <div class="fourth_span_title">
      <span class="fourth_title_span_left"><span class="fourth_title_span_right">New</span>Providence</span>
     </div>
     <h2 class="fourth_title_down_h2">Get it to your smartphone</h2>
     <form class="text-center form_fourth" action="#">
      <input class="fourth_form_input" type="email" name="email" placeholder="denis@getcraftwork.com">
      <button class="fourth_form_button"><span class="form_btn">Send Invite</span><i class="fa fa-arrow-right fa_btn"></button>
     </form>
     <div class="fourth_form_down_text">or Download From</div>
     <div class="fourth_apple"><img src="img/apple.png" alt=""></div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
 <section id="fifth">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
     <div class="fifth_slider">
      <div class="fifth_slider_item">
       <div>
        <img src="img/slider_top.png" alt="">
        <h3 class="fifth_slider_item_title">New Providence is the great UI kit</h3>
       </div>
       <div>
        <p class="fifth_slider_item_text">“Just then her head struck against the roof of the hall: in fact she was now more than nine feet high, and she at once took up the little golden key and hurried off to the garden door.”</p>
       </div>
       <div>
        <img src="img/slider_star.png" alt="">
        <img src="img/slider_star.png" alt="">
        <img src="img/slider_star.png" alt="">
        <img src="img/slider_star.png" alt="">
        <img src="img/slider_star.png" alt="">
        <h4 class="fifth_slider_name">Cameron Dowman</h4>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
 <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.arcticmodal-0.3.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/slick.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас не закрыт тег `i`

```
<button class="fourth_form_button">
  <span class="form_btn">Send Invite</span>
  <i class="fa fa-arrow-right fa_btn">
</button>
```

Добавьте закрывающий тег

```
<i class="fa fa-arrow-right fa_btn"></i>
```

Comment: Точно... Спасибо огромное за внимательность.. Несколько часов пытался понять что происходит...